# Error term between $f(x)$, its average value and value at midpoint

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a smooth function on interval $[a,b]$. Define the average $\bar{f}=\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(y)\,dy$ and $\bar{x}=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$, then for any $x\in [a,b]$, we can write

$$f(x)-\bar{f}=c(x-\bar{x})+E,$$
where $c$ is something related to $f$ and $E$ is the error term. I want to know whether it's possible to get $E=O(b-a)^2$.

By $O(b-a)^2$, I mean $\lim_{b-a\to 0}\frac{|E|}{(b-a)^2}\le C$ for some constant $C>0$.

---

What I tried: By Taylor expansion, we have
$$f(x)=f(\bar{x})+f'(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})+f''(\xi)(x-\bar{x})^2.$$
Then $f(x)-\bar{f}=f'(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})+f''(\xi)(x-\bar{x})^2+f(\bar{x})-\bar{f}$. Hence it remains to study $f(\bar{x})-\bar{f}$.

But by mean value theorem, we know 
$$f(\bar{x})-\bar{f}=f(\bar{x})-f(c)=f'(\eta)(c-\bar{x}),$$
which only gives me the first order approximation.

Is there any way to get a better result?

Comment: What do you mean by $O(b-a)^2$? Is that big-O of a constant (so basically, bounded)?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I have added an explanation of big-O. Basically I mean if let $h=b-a$, I hope $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|E|}{h^2}\le C$.

Comment: Write $f(x) = f(\overline{x}) + f'(\overline{x})\cdot (x-\overline{x}) + \frac{1}{2} f''(\xi)(x-\overline{x})^2$ for the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the second-order Taylor approximation

$$f(\bar{x})- \bar{f} = -\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b [f(x) - f(\bar{x})] \, dx \\ = -\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f'(\bar{x})(x - \bar{x}) \, dx + -\frac{1}{2(b-a)}\int_a^b f''(\xi_x)(x - \bar{x})^2 \, dx. $$

Since $b - \bar{x} = -(a - \bar{x}) = (b-a)/2,$ the first integral on the RHS vanishes.  If the second-derivative is bounded as $|f''(x)| \leqslant M$then

$$|f(\bar{x})- \bar{f}| \leqslant \frac{M}{2(b-a)}\int_a^b (x - \bar{x})^2 \, dx =\frac{M}{2(b-a)} \frac{2}{3}\frac{|b-a|^3}{8} = O(|b-a|^2)$$